# python argparse input error

Tags: python, bash, argparse

I have the following two arguments to be specified:

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "-server", help="specify the server", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-pw", "-password", help="Provide your Admin Password", required=True)
```

This works great except that my go-to "test"/dummy password has uncovered a bit of a problem.

My dummy password is `90opl;./`

if I run `./test.py -s testserver -pw 90opl;./`

I get an error because it's not interpreting `90opl;./` as `' 90opl;,./ '`

so the auth fails and then `-bash` says `./: Is a directory` (the end of the pw).

to get around this I must run `./test.py -s testserver -pw '90opl;./'` - aka single quotes must be used.

Is there a way around this??
I can't seem to find an answer online. I've tried specifying `type=str` to no avail.

Sorry if this has an obvious fix but I'm a bit of a python noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Python issue. This is a shell issue.

The Bash shell gives a specific interpretation to the `;` character in most contexts, and quoting it is the most sane and readable way to avoid this interpretation.

There is nothing Python or the `argparse` library can do about this, because `bash` interprets the command line before Python ever gets to see it.

If you **have to** type a default dummy password at the command line a zillion times... make it an easier password that doesn't contain any shell meta-characters :-P.

Comment: heh I see. I see. well alright then. I will adjust my dummy password as needed then. thanks :D